# Correct way to refer to class/instance rather than object literal property?

Tags: javascript, scope, coffeescript

I have an object 'foo', with an object literal as a property, as shown below. Inside that property, I'd like to refer to the object 'foo' rather than the object literal itself.

Can this only be done with hacks, ie, referring to the object by its variable name? Or is there a better way?

Example below - should print 'woo' on success.

```
class Foo
  myfunc: =>
    console.log('woo')
  testthing: {
    'foo':'bar'
    'baz':'boo'
    'bop': =>
      @myfunc()
  }

window.foo = new Foo

foo.testthing.bop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->
    @testthing =
      'foo':'bar'
      'baz':'boo'
      'bop': => @myfunc()
  myfunc: =>
    console.log('woo')
```

Declaring `testthing` in the constructor like this allows `@myfunc` to be bound to the 'instance' rather than the 'class'.

You could also use `'bop': @myfunc` instead of `'bop': => @myfunc()` to pass along any arguments :)

Comment: Right on the nose. Just to clarify: In the class body, `@` points to `Foo`. In the constructor, it points to the `Foo` instance being created.